# QBO3: Limit Process Templates when adding a Process

Tags: qbo3

I have a QBO3 installation with multiple `ProcessTemplates` defined. The standard `Deal/Search` UI renders a + button with dropdown list of available templates to add. I want to limit the available templates to only those templates which are marked with `ProcessTemplateType=Initial`.  How do I modify the UI to limit these options?

Answer (score 0):

The `Process/Search` panels (including `Deal/Search`) render the + options with the following method signature:

```
ProcessTemplate/Search?SiblingObject=Deal
```

You can limit the results of this method signature by defining a `Filter` to be triggered by the `SiblingObject` parameter, like this:

- Name: `Initial`
- Clause: `ProcessTemplate.ProcessTemplateType = 'Initial'`
- Parameters: `SiblingObject`

This will trigger calls to `ProcessTemplate/Seach?SiblingObject=Deal` to inject the following into the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
WHERE
  ProcessTemplate.ProcessTemplateType = 'Initial'
```